# mySQL How to properly sort this data?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with multiple timestamp entries and I am trying to list the data associated with the latest updated timestamp for each unique `bookID` entry.

The table is composed as following :

```
create table rankHistory (
id int(10),
rankUpdated timestamp,
bookId varchar(10),
currentRank int(5)
);
```

Example data :

```
INSERT INTO rankHistory
(`id`, `rankUpdated`, `bookId`,`currentRank`)
VALUES
(1, '2016-05-27 05:11:44', 'BK-001','100'),
(2, '2016-05-28 08:11:44', 'BK-001','95'),
(3, '2016-05-29 07:11:44', 'BK-001','11'),
(4, '2016-05-29 08:11:44', 'BK-001','5'),
(5, '2016-05-27 05:11:44', 'BK-002','100'),
(6, '2016-05-27 05:11:44', 'BK-002','100'),
(7, '2016-05-29 05:11:44', 'BK-002','100'),
(8, '2016-05-29 06:11:44', 'BK-002','55')
;
```

Consolidated an example in the following sqlFiddle : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b02d3/4

I'm trying to get output as following :

```
2016-05-29 08:11:44, BK-001, 5
2016-05-29 06:11:44, BK-002, 55
```

The query I tried and thought would work (I'm not very familiar with mySQL so please be gentle.. )

```
select bookId,currentRank,MAX(rankUpdated) FROM rankHistory group by bookId
```

This does show the latest timestamp entry but not it's matching data. What would be the correct way to achieve the output listed above ?

Comment: can you plz post your expected result

Comment: `2016-05-29 08:11:44, BK-001, 11` a typo?

Comment: Has done the required editing in the query it will give the required output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query :

```
select Max(RankUpdated),A.bookId,A.CurrentRank from (
select bookId,currentRank,RankUpdated FROM rankHistory 
where RankUpdated IN (select MAX(rankUpdated) FROM rankHistory group by CurrentRank)
group by bookId,currentRank) A
group by A.bookId
```

It will give the required output like below :-

```
 RankUpdated          bookId    currentRank 
 2016-05-29 08:11:44  BK-001        5
 2016-05-29 06:11:44  BK-002        55
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` which will select only the record, where another record with a newer timestamp doesn't exists.

```
SELECT * FROM rankHistory t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM rankHistory s
                 WHERE s.bookId = t.bookId AND
                       s.rankUpdated > t.rankUpdated)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
select r.bookId, r.currentRank, r.rankUpdated from rankHistory r
inner join (
    select id, bookId, MAX(currentRank) from (
        select id, bookId, currentRank from rankHistory
        order by rankUpdated desc
    )  t group by t.bookId
) t on t.id = r.id
```

Comment: Thnk you for your help

Answer (score 0):

use `join`:

```
select a.bookId,a.currentRank,a.rankUpdated from rankHistory a join (
select bookId,MAX(rankUpdated) as maxrank FROM rankHistory group by bookId) b on a.bookID = b.bookId and a.rankUpdated=b.maxrank
```

see the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b02d3/9